# Transact SQL - Using a NOT EXISTS clause instead of NOT IN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to modify this Transact SQL statement to use a `NOT EXISTS` clause instead of `NOT IN`. I have used the search engine and I am having difficulty applying the examples I have found.

```
SELECT StudentId 
FROM Students 
WHERE School NOT IN (SELECT School FROM ClosedSchools)
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `Students` and `ClosedSchools` have a `SchoolId` field:

```
SELECT StudentId 
FROM Students stu
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT School 
    FROM ClosedSchools clo
    WHERE clo.SchoolId = stu.SchoolId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  StudentId
FROM    Students AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT School
                     FROM   ClosedSchools AS b
                     WHERE  a.School = b.School )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.StudentId 
  FROM Students s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM ClosedSchools 
                     where ClosedSchools.School = s.School 
                  )
```

or

```
SELECT s.StudentId 
  FROM Students s
  LEFT JOIN ClosedSchools 
        on ClosedSchools.School = s.School 
 WHERE ClosedSchools.School is null;
```